# Writing the space of all possible solutions using a homogenous and particular solution

Tags: linear-algebra

System of equations: 
$$\begin{align} 2w + 3x -2y +z &=-1
\\6w+ 10x \quad      +6z&=14
\\3w +2.5x -15y -4.5z &= -35.5 \end{align}$$

Particular solution to the system of equations: 
$A$= $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$

Give the space of all possible solutions to the system of equations, as a linear combination of vectors (this should be sum of 3 vectors, some of which will have variables as coefficients)

So fort he first part I needed to solve the homogeneous set of equations. I was able to do so and got a solution set. Now, I know the the general solution consists of the particular solution + the homogenous solution but how do I got about writing the space of all possible solutions? Step by step explanation please!

Comment: $\left[\matrix{*\cr *\cr*\cr *\cr}\right]+s \cdot \left[\matrix{*\cr *\cr*\cr *\cr}\right]+t \cdot \left[\matrix{*\cr *\cr*\cr *\cr}\right]$ if the homogenous solutions are parameterized with two variables (i.e. if the solution space is 2-dimensional).

Comment: I'm sorry can you elaborate on what this means. How exactly do I use the particular solution...?

Comment: The first vector is your particular solution. The other vectors represent the general homogeneous solution. If the homogeneous solutions are parameterized by $x_1=2s+4t$, $x_2=3s-5t$, $x_3=s$, and $x_4=t$, then the homogeneous solution is $s\cdot\left[\matrix{2\cr 3\cr 1\cr 0\cr}\right]+t \cdot \left[\matrix{4\cr -5\cr 0\cr 1\cr}\right]$.